# Can Image Id be passed from OnClick Event in this way by passing its position to getItemId?

Tags: android, android-intent, gridview

I made a custom gridview of images and associated texts. When clicked on an Image, I want it to be displayed in a new DetailActivity. But I am having some problem in displaying it. When I click on any Item in gridview the app is crashing.

Can anyone point out the problem in my code.

This is the code of the Custom Grid Adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
int[] imagesId;
String[] names;
long imageId;
public static LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int[] LimagesId, String[] Lnames) {
    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.imagesId = LimagesId;
    this.names = Lnames;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    //define rows
    rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesId[position]);
    holder.textView.setText(names[position]);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked " + names[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            imageId = getItemId(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image",imageId);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rowView; }
}
```

This is the code of DetailActivity

```
public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 int[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    long position = intent.getLongExtra("image", R.drawable.image1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_imageView);
    Integer pos = (int) (long) position;
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[pos]);
}
```

Comment: @Boss I've edited it. Still its not solved. Do I need to use constructor?

Comment: instead of passing `getItemId(position);` pass just the `position` to the intent. Constructor!! i don't think so?

Comment: If its still not resolved, please post the logcat

Comment: Ah, the old trick of disregarding any type of documentation and have others debug your code, the joys of debugging without the stacktrace. I'm assuming you're looking for downvotes, so here you go.

Comment: @2Dee  I m a beginner in android. My question may be a stupid one. Sorry about that. But you please note that I dont welcome your assumptions about me here as comment for my **question**.

Comment: You answered my comment, but conveniently avoided to read the constructive comment of Boss right above, which is exactly what I was talking about. Being new to Android is not the problem, it's your lack of basic common sense that hinders your capacity to learn...

Comment: @2Dee I was facing some error in emulator/AndroidStudio. That was the reason I could not get the logcat. BTW my problem got solved by the answer during that time. If you have to tell any thing related to my question you are welcome. Please note that I dont need your personal advice. I just need answers.

Comment: Yeah, problem solved but answer is still not accepted. And I'm convinced your reason for not posting the LogCat is a lie, plain and simple. You just need answers but I see no reason to make that easy for you, since you're just a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)...

Comment: @2Dee Its not a platform to argue. Please leave. And I dont have time to hear your personal views.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, [requiring a stacktrace when dealing with crashes is far from being a "personnal view"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm trying to make you understand why your question is bad so you can stop polluting the website, I don't care if you like it or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there is a lot wrong with your code.

1. getId method in the adapter is not the ID if the image, its a unique ID used in the adapter.
2. That imageId[] is not initialized anywhere.
3. you should be passing holder.imageview.getId() in the intent.
4. The intent extra should be getIntExtra() not getLongExtra() after you make the above changes.
5. Once you have successfully passed the correct imageId, there is no need for that imageId[] as far as i can tell with the code you posted. Just use the int you received from the intent inside setImageResource.

Make these changes and let us know how it goes, I will edit this answer if there are more errors or I missed something.

Edit: Well, you changed the code in the answer a good bit, so some of may points may appear to be irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you. I changed code as per your answer.  What should I give as the default one when using `getIntExtra`. When I gave this I am geting the default image only. `int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image", R.drawable.image1);`

Comment: I would make it like "-1" Then you can check for that -1 and you'll know you had an error which you could then handle. -1 would never be a number passed by that intent.

Comment: Now it appears blank. I will post the changed code. Please take a look.

Comment: `int imageId = holder.imageView.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",imageId);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }`

Comment: This is the how I get this intent `int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image", -1);`

Comment: Since you have that imageId[] populated now, as long as the positions are correct, you can pass the adapter position through the intent, then setImageResource(imageId[position]). So get rid of the holder.imageView.getId() and just use the position value.